# Multiple updates in rules is throwing exception

Tags: java, drools

We have used drools 7.7 to write rules . We are trying to write multiple rules , in each rule we have updated facts in action and trying to use updated facts in next rule condition, but drools is throwing below exception.

We are running drools in SEQUENTIAL MODE . with following configurations :-

```
 kieSessionBuilder.setKieBaseMap(
        ruleGroupId, kieHelper.build(SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC, SequentialOption.YES));

Rule 1
Salience "1"
no-loop
when
$allocatedQuantity : AllocatedQuantity(receivedQuantity<allocatedQuantity)
$inventory : Inventory (location == 'A')
then
$allocatedQuantity.setReceivedQuantity($allocatedQuantity.getReceivedQuantity()+ $inventory.getQuantity());
update($allocatedQuantity);
end

Rule 2
Salience "2"
no-loop
when
$allocatedQuantity : AllocatedQuantity(receivedQuantity<allocatedQuantity)
$inventory : Inventory (location == 'B')
then
$allocatedQuantity.setReceivedQuantity($allocatedQuantity.getReceivedQuantity()+ $inventory.getQuantity());
update($allocatedQuantity);
end


Rule 3
Salience "3"
no-loop
when
$allocatedQuantity : AllocatedQuantity(receivedQuantity<allocatedQuantity)
$inventory : Inventory (location == 'C')
then
$allocatedQuantity.setReceivedQuantity($allocatedQuantity.getReceivedQuantity()+ $inventory.getQuantity());
update($allocatedQuantity);
end

Rule 4
Salience "4"
no-loop
when
$allocatedQuantity : AllocatedQuantity(receivedQuantity<allocatedQuantity)
$inventory : Inventory (location == 'D')
then
$allocatedQuantity.setReceivedQuantity($allocatedQuantity.getReceivedQuantity()+ $inventory.getQuantity());
update($allocatedQuantity);
end


Rule 5
Salience "5"
no-loop
when
$allocatedQuantity : AllocatedQuantity(receivedQuantity<allocatedQuantity)
$inventory : Inventory (location == 'E')
then
$allocatedQuantity.setReceivedQuantity($allocatedQuantity.getReceivedQuantity()+ $inventory.getQuantity());
update($allocatedQuantity);
end
```

till 4th rule it executes but in 5th rule it throws below exception :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doLeftUpdates(PhreakFromNode.java:181) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doNode(PhreakFromNode.java:64) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:387) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:333) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.doRiaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:606) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:533) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:373) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:333) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:169) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:127) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:212) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:87) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1308) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1299) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1283) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.execute(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:281) ~[drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar:7.7.0.Final]

    at
```

Comment: do you still get the error after changing the line to `E`?

Comment: Yes.. Error is still there